# clave de matriz indefinida en PHP

Tags: php

tengo un index.html que es un login basico con css

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Prueba de conexion</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head> 
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="info">
                <p class="txt-1">GRACIAS POR VISITARNOS</p>
                <p class="txt-2"> Bienvenido de nuevo </p>
                <p class="txt-3" >Este es un pequeño login para validad
                </p>
            </div>
            <form action="validar.php" method="post" class="form">
                <h2>Login</h2>
                <div class="inputs">
                    <input type="txt" class="box" placeholder="Ingresa tu correo" nombre="user">
                    <input type="password" class="box" placeholder="Ingresa tu contraseña" nombre="pswd">
                    <input type="submit" value="login" class="submit">
                </div>
            </form>

        </div>
        
    </body>
    </html>
```

hice una conexion a mariadb con php que si me funciona

```
            <?php
        $server="";
            $user="";
            $pwd="";
            $db="";
            $conexion =new mysqli($server,$user,$pwd,$db);
            if($conexion){
                echo 'Conexion exitosa';
            }else{
                echo 'Sin conexion';
            }
        ?>
```

pero cada tengo el problema de que si estraigo los valores de los input de mi html para pasarlos a php, me sale que no se a definido las variables user y pswd

```
            <?php
        include ('Conexion.php');
            $crr = $_POST['user'];
            $pswd = $_POST['pswd'];
            echo $crr . "<br>" . $pswd;
        ?>
```

aun no entiendo porque, estoy usando Visual Studio Code

Comment: cambia el atributo de los input `nombre="user">` -> `name="user">`, es debido a eso q no les encuentra

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Porque en el formulario debes colocar un identificador de cada campo.

Prueba con

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Prueba de conexion</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head> 
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="info">
                <p class="txt-1">GRACIAS POR VISITARNOS</p>
                <p class="txt-2"> Bienvenido de nuevo </p>
                <p class="txt-3" >Este es un pequeño login para validad
                </p>
            </div>
            <form action="validar.php" method="post" class="form">
                <h2>Login</h2>
                <div class="inputs">
                    <input type="txt" id="user" name="user" class="box" placeholder="Ingresa tu correo">
                    <input type="password" id="pswd" name="pswd" class="box" placeholder="Ingresa tu contraseña">
                    <input type="submit" value="login" class="submit">
                </div>
            </form>

        </div>
        
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Tienes razon, ya funciono, muchas gracias

Comment: No, esta respuesta no es correcta. El atributo correcto es `name`. El atributo `id` no tiene nada que ver.

Comment: Eres demasiado cerrado en argumentar, el atributo **name** está en la respuesta y es el que le permite solventar el problema, el **id** es algo que también debe manejarlo y no dejarlo fuera porque sirve para mucho. Si te basas en la palabra **identificador** que usé, el name identifica a dicho campo no me refería expresamente al id. Te recuerdo que el OP puede aceptar una respuesta cuando esta solventa su problema, no siempre va a ser una respuesta "correcta" a criterio de todos, o se te olvidó eso??

Comment: El OP acepto la respuesta porque funcionó, no porque lo que dice sea correcto. Lo real es que el id nada tiene que ver con la solución. Lo que hiciste y no lo mencionas fue corregir, por ejemplo, `nombre="user"` por `name="user"` y esa es la verdadera solución.

Comment: Esa es tu opinión. Vuelves a ser cerrado en argumentar, cualquiera pensaría que dices que el OP es tonto solo porque no expuso que entendió el cambio o por el hecho que yo no se lo clarifiqué expresamente. Me gusta pensar que no solo copian, sino que ven los cambios y averiguan más, aunque no vengan a decirlo acá. Yo no voy a dejar de colocar el **id** a las etiquetas, es aconsejable ponerlas siempre. Igual alguien ya se lo dijo en el comment de la pregunta.

Comment: Me parece que te estas tomando esto demasiado personal. Obviamente esta es mi opinión sobre tu respuesta, vos podes pensar distinto y esta bien. Lo único que espero es que sepas que hay una diferencia importante entre, sugerir hacer algo porque consideras que es correcto, a dar la respuesta correcta. Dicho sea de paso, considero que poner `id` por poner, no trae ningún beneficio. PD: todos los elementos pueden tener `id`, no solo los `input`

Comment: Debo recordarte que en SOes prevalece mas la respuesta aceptada que la correcta? Yo manejaba el concepto de respuesta correcta pero me hicieron cambiar ese concepto porque el sitio así funciona. Yo ya dejé claro que es TU opinión y tengo todo el derecho de refutarla, sino quieres que la gente se sienta molesta por tus opiniones considera usar más el lenguaje positivo. Por lo demás considero que seguir con esto no contribuye en nada...